# Accuracy in relative geographic positioning on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, gps, css-position

From what I've read GPS is accurate up to a certain point, but there can be some error between what the GPS gives you and the real location. How about when using GPS for relative positioning? Let's say we have two points that are pretty close to each other (less than 100 meters). If you measure the distance between the coordinates given by iPhones or Android based phones can you achieve true accuracy? If not, is there a way to achieve true accuracy when measuring distance between two close by points?

Comment: What do you mean by "true accuracy"?  GPS will only ever be accurate, at the best, to perhaps 50cm or so.  A few metres in most real world scenarios.  GPS accuracy is affected by the quality of the receiver (so not Android vs iOS but Apple vs Samsung ;)), weather, sun activity etc etc.

Comment: I suspected hardware has also something to do with it :) Thanks for the correction. I read that with DGPS you can get up to 10cm accuracy. Even 50cm accuracy is good enough. But a few meters error is too big since the whole area is only a few square meters size.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a way. GPS isn't accurate enough, but if you have good enough imagery from Google Earth you can have a pretty accurate measurement there. Also, do you have tall buildings in the area that you may know the height of? There might be another way if you do through simple geometry.

Comment: What I need is to position people in a relatively small space. That space can be open or it can be a room inside a building which makes this even harder. If the room is 10x10 and I have a 10 meter radius accuracy I can't use this solution to position the people in that room. But what if I use relative positioning? If the error is the same for all those points then they might all have the same shift from their real location but relative to each other their position will be accurate.

Comment: You have no other option other than using a retractable ruler.